# Get Component from the process

Tags: java

I have the following code to launch classes in a new process:

```
public final class JavaProcess {

    private JavaProcess() {}        

    public static int exec(Class klass) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
        String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String className = klass.getCanonicalName();

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-cp", classpath, className);
        Process process = builder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        return process.exitValue();
    }
}
```

and I use it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    CustomFrame F = new CustomFrame();
    System.out.println(JavaProcess.exec(MyApplet.class));  //Start an applet in a separate JVM.
}
```

How can I add that applet to my JFrame? I tried the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    CApplet CP = new CApplet(null, false, 765, 503);

    //Perhaps serialize it.
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out);
    oos.writeObject(CP);
    oos.close();
}
```

and read the serialized object and add that to my JFrame?
How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think that you can do this, not in this way.

Comment: You can't.  They exist in two different JVM's and I'm not sure that even if your tried connecting the two via a RMI server that the system would like you serializing Swing components that have begin realized...it might get thingy about the native peer reference.  The question is, why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: Not possible. That applet is in a separate process space.

Comment: I wanted to do this because Browsers like Firefox create seperate processes per tab for applets and they all share the same TabPane and I really wanted to learn how it was done.

Comment: Did you try de-serializing that? It's intriguing. I would like to know if that worked.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: this is not how to "learn how it was done". Just move along to something reasonable. I'm sure that they use native code as there can't be a Java-only solution.

Comment: Yeah, this might be better suited for programmers.se. Interesting though.

Comment: This makes me sad. Every time I want to do something unique in Java, I'm told it can't be done way too often. Thanks. I'll try doing it in C++ then.